# Use multiple instance of hangfire with single database

Tags: hangfire

Has anyone used multiple instances of [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) (in different applications) with same SQL DB for configuration. So instead of creating new SQL DB for each hangfire instance i would like to share same DB with multiple instances.

As per the hangfire [documentation here](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/running-multiple-server-instances.html) it is supported since v1.5 However forum discussion [here](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/single-db-for-multiple-applications/1798) and [here](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/using-one-hangfire-db-for-multiple-applications/546/7) shows we still have issues running multiple instances with same db

**Update 1**
So based on suggestions and [documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html) i configired hangfire to use queue

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
   ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
        app.UseHangfireServer(new BackgroundJobServerOptions()
        {
            Queues = new string[] { "instance1" }
        });
   }
```

Method to invoke

```
[Queue("instance1")]
public async Task Start(int requestID)
{

}
```

This is how i Enqueue job

```
 _backGroundJobClient.Enqueue<IPrepareService>(x => x.Start(request.ID));
```

however when i check [JobQueue] table the new job has queue name `default` and because of that hangfire will never pickup that job because it picks up jobs for queues.

I think is a bug

**Update 2**

Found one more thing. I am using instance of `IBackgroundJobClient`. The instance is automatically get injected by .Net Core's inbuilt container.

So if i use instance to enqueue the job then hangfire creates new job with `default` queue name

```
 _backGroundJobClient.Enqueue<IPrepareService>(x => x.Start(request.ID));
```

However if i use static method, then hangfire creates new job with configured queue name `instance1`

```
  BackgroundJob.Enqueue<IPrepareService>(x => x.Start(prepareRequest.ID));
```

How do i configure hangfire in .Net Core so the instance of IBackgroundJobClient will use configure queue name ?

Comment: Have you tried using different queue names for different instances? If yes, still has the same issue? I have not tried it, but think that using different queue names for different instances should not mix up the things. Can you also post your code, which you have tried?

Comment: Doing it without problem. What issues do you have?

Comment: No i haven't used it yet. But that is the confusion. You are saying use different queue names but hangfire documentation says `You aren’t required to have additional configuration to support multiple background processing servers in the same process since Hangfire 1.5, just skip the article. Server identifiers are now generated using GUIDs, so all the instance names are unique` http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/running-multiple-server-instances.html

Comment: ..and also the in generated SQL tables i don't see `[Server].[Id]` has foreign key relationship with any other table. So how does hangfire identify a job belongs to particular instance?

Comment: I run multiple instances on a single database. No queues necessary.

Comment: @mason are all the instances of same application or different applications.? In my case i have two different applications trying to share same database. So they have different methods

Comment: We have one application that enqueues the job and another that processes the job, and we can have multiple instances of either application. In both cases, they're working off an interface that describes the job.

Comment: it does make sense when you have microservice architecture. You dont want to end up with multiple small databases.

Comment: Most microservice architectures I've seen absolutely preach having small databases that are consumed by a single service rather than monolithic databases. Especially if there's no need for them to share the database, such as processing different sets of jobs in Hangfire.

Answer (score 17):

This is possible by simply setting the SQL server options with a different schema name for each instance.

Instance 1:

```
configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(
    configuration.GetConnectionString("Hangfire"),
    new SqlServerStorageOptions { SchemaName = "PrefixOne" }
);
```

Instance 2:

```
configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(
    configuration.GetConnectionString("Hangfire"),
    new SqlServerStorageOptions { SchemaName = "PrefixTwo" }
);
```

Both instances use same connection string and will create two instances of all the required tables with the prefix specified in the settings.

Queues are used for having separate queues in the same Hangfire instance. If you want to use different queues you'll need to specify the queues you want the IBackgroundJobClient to listen to and then specify that queue when creating jobs. This doesn't sound like what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: when using instance of `IBackgroundJobClient` i dont see any option where i can specify queue name. The `Enqueue` method does not take queue name as parameter

Comment: `RecurringJob` manager has built in queue support. If you want to queue immediately in a specific queue you'll need to use `IBackgroundJobClient.Create()` with an `EnqueuedState` setting the queue for the `IState` parameter. Alternatively you can add the `Queue` attribute on the method you are calling. However none of this is required if you don't need different queues and just want two hangfire instances in same database.

Comment: Very useful. I thought Queue can be used to isolate different applications, but later I found in HF Queues are useful only in single application. Schemas are the best way to address the issue. Thanks

Comment: [Hangfire.MAMQSqlExtension](https://github.com/GeXiaoguo/Hangfire.MAMQSqlExtension) allows jobs to be isolated by queues. No code sharing is needed between multiple servers

Comment: @XiaoguoGe make your library available to .Net Core

Comment: @JohnNyingi It is already. The usage examples contain both .NetFramework and .NetCore

Comment: I just saw the implementation its really good